# API Gateway issue - internal server error in POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

My Lambda GET code -

```
try {
    const { httpMethod, body, pathParameters } = event;

    if (httpMethod === 'GET') {
      const { id } = pathParameters;
      // READ operation
      const params = {
        TableName: 'Emp_Basic',
        Key: { id: { N: id } }
      };
      const command = new GetItemCommand(params);
      const result = await dynamoDBClient.send(command);

      if (!result.Item) {
        return {
          statusCode: 404,
          body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Item not found' })
        };
      }

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result.Item)
        }
      };
```

My API gateway endpoint looks like this -
https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test/employee/125

I have configure the route as:

[image]

I have kept all * in CORS fields. No authorization or authentication was attached to it.

When I execute the above API with GET request, I'm get internal server error. Anything I missed?